# UINavigationController shows RootViewController before showing topViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to show view controller which is 2nd view controller in a navigation view controller. What I want to show RegistraionViewController if join is tapped. Based on that. I push registrationViewController to the navigation Controller where LoginViewController is rootView Controller. Now the issue is when Join is Tapped. It Should show registrationView Controller but it shows Login screen and after a delay of about half second. It shows registration screen. My Code is as follows:

```
           if  let navC = self.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
            {
                if  let vc = navC.viewControllers.first as? LoginViewController
                {
                    if let registerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegistrationViewControllerIdentifier") as? RegistrationViewController
                    {
                        var view = navC.view
                        vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(registerVC, animated: false)

                    }
                }

            }
```

I have also tried by changing the transition of views and giving animation time as 0. But no luck. Which is :

```
if let registerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegistrationViewControllerIdentifier") as? RegistrationViewController
{

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, animations: {
                if let view = self.navigationController?.view
                {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(registerVC, animated: false)
                    UIView.setAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.None, forView:view , cache: false)

                }

                }, completion: {
                    (value: Bool) in
            })

}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating the navigation controller with rootViewController and where are you displaying it?

Comment: it's from storyboard. Assigned rootVC already in Storyboard

Comment: What method is this code you posted being executed in?

Comment: it's in tabbarController's ViewDidLoad

Comment: I've also tried it in LoginViewController's ViewWillAppear and LoadView()

Comment: Have you tried just setting the viewControllers array on the navigation controller directly?  Something like: `navC.setViewControllers(navC.viewControllers + [registerVC], animated: false)`

Comment: Yup. Did this also. And it behaves strange. It still shows view controller for that particular time and then shows black screen if i remove all Viewcontrollers

Comment: debug shows nothing in array of viewControllers bt it still shows the viewController for a short sec